# How to create a unique web page address in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Is there a standard way to create unique web page address in ASP.NET? I'm sending surveys to customers and will be including a link to the web page.  For example:

http://www.mysurveypages.foo/survey/UniqueID

I would then customize the survey based on who I sent it to. I know it can be done by passing in a unique parameter to a page but I curious about doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to map your url structure onto a particular page and parameter collection.  Essentially, it allows you to convert parts of the url into url parameters for your page.  This works in standard WebForms and is the basis upon which MVC chooses the appropriate controller/action signature to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Yup like dcp said GUID is a reasonable solution  `http://mywebsite.com/survey.aspx?ID=GUID`

Comment: Generally I'd say just to upvote his answer rather than repeating it, but his answer doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are going to sent the survey to a list of users.

```
List<User> users = GetSurveyUsers();
foreach(User u in users)
{
   Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
   //Then store the user-guid pair into DB or XML...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The question is not "how do I generate the unique id," he wants to know how to use RESTful URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would seem to be making UniqueID an incrementing field that can be used to get the appropriate user information out of the database.  You could use numbers, or a Guid, or some alpha-numeric value, it really doesn't matter.

If you go with ASP.Net MVC then it is quite easy to map the Url (like the one you specified) to a controller action which gets the ID passed in as a parameter.  Otherwise you will probably want to look into [some sort of Url rewriting](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iis+url+rewriting) to make sure the Url can be nice and pretty.

Answer (score 0):

A GUID approach is safest, if you're able to store it somewhere. If not you could use some existing unique data (e.g. customer id or email address) either directly (but be careful about leaking sensitive data) or hashed (but need to consider collisions).